# Android - How to end a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onpause, activity-finish

In my application I have a navigation drawer, and the way my app works is there is only one activity and if you select something from the Navigation drawer it starts/replaces the current fragment. How Can I make it so that when something is selected from the navigation drawer and a new fragment starts the old fragment ends

I cant do

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

because that would kill the app since there is only one activity.

How do I kill the fragment?

EDIT: my fragment transaction

```
Home HomeFragment = new Home();
        transaction.replace(R.id.llhome, HomeFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
              mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

thanks

Answer (score 11):

Just call:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dynamic fragments, set up via a `FragmentTransaction`, you could run a transaction to `replace()` the old fragment with the new one.

Comment: @user222786: Then I fail to understand your concern. You have successfully replaced the fragment.

Comment: I have not, the fragment doesnt die, if I went to 5 different fragments, I would have to press back 5 times to get back to the home screen. The fragments arent being killed

Comment: @user222786 Remove `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`.

Comment: @user222786: I agree with MaciejGórski. If you don't want to add the transaction to the back stack, don't add the transaction to the back stack.